# virsh list command not showing any domain

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a VM on Fedora 18 host using QEMU/KVM and libvirtd. Now, when I fire up the virsh and give list command, it doesn't show any domain running, though my VM is running quite fine. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It may caused by the user you issued the virsh command. It's normal that you start your VM by sudo but you can see nothing under your other accounts.

You can see your VMs via `sudo virsh list --all`

Comment: Thanks! I was missing sudo